# How to create PIVOT for multiple lines

Tags: sql, pivot, rows

I am looking for a help on PIVOT (sql).

the base table:

```
ID      COLUMN_NAME                    VALUE        ROW_INDEX
017QZ   Course Completion Confirmed?    Yes             1
017QZ   Course Completion Confirmed?    Yes             2
017QZ   Course Type                     A&S             1
017QZ   Course Expiry Date              04/30/2021      1
017QZ   Course Type                     Life Upgrade    2
017QZ   Date Completion Verified        08/17/2020      1
017QZ   Course Provider                 R Publishing    2
017QZ   Course Completed Date           04/30/2020      1
017QZ   Course Provider                 R Publishing    1
017QZ   Course Expiry Date              05/01/2021      2
017QZ   Course Completed Date           05/01/2020      2
```

I need just this output: Course Name and Expired date.

```
ID       A&S        Life Upgrade
017QZ   04/30/2021  05/01/2021
```

I was able to achieve this by using 2 separate PIVOT views but I am wondering is there more efficient way?

Thank you!

Comment: What do the columns mean? Under what logic are you aggregating? What significance is similar rows with different `row_index`?

Comment: this is the way the table is organized. "Column_name " column has column mane in normal way table and Value column holds the value for specific column.
there are right now 8 diffrent courses in that column. Some IDs have 2 or more courses.

Comment: But what do the result columns mean `A&S` and `Life Upgrade`? And do you only want this result for one `ID` and `Row_index` or for all of them

Comment: column result for A&S and  others courses (there are 8 active courses now) - is date the course is taken.

Comment: there are may be few courses taken, or just one,  no pattern
my first PIVOT gives me 2 rows for this ID:
```
select * from  (  SELECT ID,  GROUP_Name,  TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME,   ROW_INDEX,  v.Attribute_Value 
FROM dbo.BAPPSPECTABLE_VALUE  v 
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'COURSES'  ) as SourceTable
PIVOT
(
 MAX(Attribute_Value) 
 FOR COLUMN_NAME in ([Course Completed Date],
      [Course Completion Confirmed?], 
      [Course Expiry Date], 
      [Course Provider],
      [Course Type],
      [Date Completion Verified])
 ) as PVT
```

Comment: then another PIVOT gives me what I want:

select * 
from 
( 
 SELECT 
 

   v.ID,
   V.[Course Type],
   V.[Course Expiry Date] 
   FROM V_ICOBC_COURSE_PIVOT  v 
    

) as SourceTable
PIVOT
(
 MAX([Course Expiry Date]) 
 FOR[Course Type] in ([Ethics and Professional Practice (Quebec)],
      [LLQP - Accident & Sickness only] ,
      [LLQP Full - Life, Accident & Sickness],
      [Upgrade to Life, Accident & Sickness from Accident & Sickness],
      [A&S],
      [Life Upgrade],
      [Life and A&S],
      [Other]
      )
      
 ) as PVT

Comment: can this be one PIVOT or something else? I understand I can combine code into one but i am looking for better solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want conditional aggregation?

```
select id,
       max(case when row_index = 1 and column_name = 'Course Expiry Date' then value end) as a_and_s,
       max(case when row_index = 2 and column_name = 'Course Expiry Date' then value end) as life_upgrade
from base
group by id
```

Comment: I do not think it would work as you cannot predict how many row_index values  it might be in atable  per each ID.

Comment: And I need to know course name and expiration date as it affects licensing